# how to change install an update dialog message text

Tags: android

in my app there is a new upgrade
I download my new app version to the sd card and open the apk file by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(oFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
oActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

code block. 
**i want to change message on the dialog**

[the image](http://s1209.photobucket.com/user/iuzunok/media/Android/install.png.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling exactly that one Activity with your Intent, that does the work. This particular Activity has the particular layout shown in the image. You can have an Activity that starts with the same Intent and that looks different. Nevertheless, the new Activity wouldn't do the work necessary to install the apk-file.

It's all about taking care, that no App can bypass the rights handling and needs to get rights granted by the user and nobody else (especially no App)

In short: No, not possible.