# change delete application confirmation dialogue box 's message

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created an app that do some tasks and I want to unistall after doing that task so I have lunched this intent

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:pckage_name");
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

but I want to change the default message of the dialog box.
Is that possible ?

Comment: The uninstallIntent is part of Android. Even if you can change it, I don't think you should.

Comment: not Possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454974/how-to-change-install-an-update-dialog-message-text